The PBR metal material does not look like metal
I downloaded a free PBR metal material and applied it to my model. But it does not look like metal at all. I used this material in Blender in another PC before and it seemed fine. What could be causing the problem?


It looked something like this before:


Hello it looks like metal to me, what do you mean exactly? Do you want it more glossy?

@moonboots hi. I edited the post with a screenshot of how it should look like

could you please pack the images and share the file?

@moonboots I hope posting links is not against the rules. Here's the link: https://cc0-textures.com/t/cc0t-metal-012

it sems good to me: https://i.postimg.cc/59SSfGTB/1.jpg but I would have prefered that you shared your file so that we can guess why you think it's bad

The image textures are not plugged in the UV coordinates

@moonboots yes here you go: https://filebin.net/v2ofuikeeva38jxm

@Gorgious Is this necessary? I don't remember doing it before

You are still not sharing your blend file, these are the jpgs

@Gorgious No. Procedural textures like Noise etc. use generated coordinates by default. Image textures use UVs by default.

Very ignorant of me, but while checking @moonboots 's shader nodes, I realized that I should put a Normal Map vector between the normal map texture and the BSDF shader. I also didn't put the displacement map which I don't think would matter because I don't have much vertices in my model.

How normal map work
Out of the box, Normal maps are just regular RGB images, and will be treated as such if you plug them as-is in a shader node's normal input. The shader needs to somehow read them as vectors, where RGB channels are XYZ orientations: the direction of the "perturbed normal" at each pixel. Not only that, but some normal maps also need a different UV set, might also use a different space (most commonly Tangent, but could be Object or World space), and need some form of power adjustment.
Why an extra node
One may think by reading the above that, the software could just assume we are going to plug a normal map in the normal input and not require an additional node. And that is the approach some softwares have.
But the issue is, normal maps are not the only way to affect a shader's perturbed normals. I.E. we have bump (or height) maps: BW images where each pixel's value represents the relative height of the pixel, and the difference between pixel neighbors makes the perturbed normal. That one too needs its own settings.
Some sofwares do not require to manually specify the texture as being a normal map, because they either only allow normal maps ever, or they offer a specific input for each normal-tinkering-method available at the cost of GUI crowding. Some softwares like Blender use an in-between approach where you have one normal input for everything, and you use additional nodes to your liking.
Hence, we have the Normal Map node, but also the Bump Node.

Unrelated to the issue, but the metalness map is a monochrome pure white, in other words a waste of memory, and could be replaced by manually setting your Principled BSDF node's metallic to 1. For the displacement, vertices can always be added with modifiers and whatnot. But here you only have small surface detail in your displacement map, so unless you were to make a macro-style render, it would be useless.
Hence your shader could be simplified to this:

